# CSS Container Positioning

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm having a little trouble with css

I have a container in my  jsp webpage that is styled with a div and works perfectly until I put in another div tag to style certain elements and then for some reason these elements are then placed outside of the container.

Here's the CSS code:

```
.container 
{
position: relative;
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #cccccc;
background:#ffffff; 
}

div.ex1
{
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 150px;
width:150px;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid gray;
}
```

Here's the jsp code:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="DTO.Product" %>
<%@ page import="DAO.ListTabletsDao" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-    8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">



</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

    <img src="computer_banner_blue.gif" alt="banner">

    <div class="nav">
    <ul> <li><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li><li><a href="tablets.jsp">Tablets</a></li>
        <li><a href="laptops.jsp">Laptops</a></li><li><a   href="computers.jsp">Computers</a></li>
        <li><a href="printers.jsp">Printers</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.jsp">Contact</a></li> <li><a href="about.jsp">About</a>      </li>   </ul>
    </div>

    <form action="UserActionServlet" method="post" name="searchForm">

        <input type="text" size="20" name="searchProduct">

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search">

    </form>

    <div class ="tabHeader">
    <h1>Tablets</h1>
    </div>


<%
ListTabletsDao prod = new ListTabletsDao();

List<Product> prods = prod.getDesc();
request.getSession().setAttribute("Prods", prods);
prods = (List)(request.getSession().getAttribute("Prods"));

int numId;
int y = 0;
if (prods != null){

for (Product p: prods){
  numId = p.getProduct_id();
  y++;
%>
<div class="ex<%=y%>">


 <center>
     <%=p.getTitle()%> <br> <img width="100" height="100" src="<%=p.getImageUrl()%>"> 
 <a href="productInfo.jsp?productId=<%=(numId)%>"><button>more info</button></a>

  <%=p.getPrice()%>
</center>


      </div>
<%
}
}
%>

</body>
<div>
</html>
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe post the html/example html aswell?

Comment: yes. a jsfiddle would help us to help you

Comment: Added the html for you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test and appears to be working. The issue is that you may need to add a height otherwise the container div is collapsing. Think of relative like fixed and it has no height so it is "iced" into position. It has to do with using relative and absolute.

here is a link to further education that might help further explain. http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
.container 
{
position: relative;
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #cccccc;
background:#ffffff; 
height:400px;
}

div.ex1
{
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 150px;
width:150px;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid gray;
}
</style>
</head>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ex1"> This is the inside div</div>
  </div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Great, works perfect! Thanks....Is there a way to dynamically set it by any chance?

Comment: What are you looking to dynamically change? Please be as specific as possible. Are you wanting to change the CSS using code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. What I'm doing is displaying results from a database and depending on the query different amounts of results are displayed, so i want to change the size of the container to be able to fit around them all.

Comment: If you have several elements why do you want to use absolute positioning on the first div? If you have several more items coming into play then just use margins and padding. I will leave a different answer. One sec

Answer (score 1):

Here is using the box model concept in CSS. This can be expanded even further. I am not a big fan of w3schools for a few reasons, but here is a link to explain further. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

I hope that this helps. You need to dig further into CSS from what I can tell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
.container 
{
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
padding:5px 30px 5px 30px;
background:#ffffff; 
height:100%;
border:green 1px solid;
}

div.ex1
{
margin:0 0 0 0;
padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
width:150px;
border:1px solid gray;
}
#outterWrapper{
    border:solid red 1px;
    padding:20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<div id="outterWrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="ex1"> This is the inside div</div>
    <!-- ADDING 10PX BETWEEN THE DIV'S USING CSS -->
    <div class="ex1"> This is the inside div</div>
    <div class="ex1"> This is the inside div</div>
    <div class="ex1"> This is the inside div</div>
    <div class="ex1"> This is the inside div</div>
  </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
</div><!-- END OUTTER WRAPPER -->
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, this helps alot

Comment: Your welcome. Let me know if you have any other specific questions about css that I can help out on. Also you can place all those divs next to one another or let text wrap using the style float:left; or float:right; then using a div <div style="clear:both;"></div> The clear command div comes after the float elements to stop any lower items from moving upward on the page as a simple answer.